# customize key binding on emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

```
(defun foo ()
    message "hello")
```

I want to binding the function foo to key 'ctl + l' in the shell mode
can someone show me the code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you need to fix your brackets and make the function interactive.

```el
(defun foo ()
  (interactive)
  (message "hello"))
```

Then you need can bind this to a key while in `shell-mode`.

```el
(local-set-key (kbd "C-i") 'foo)
```

To make it permanent, add a function to set this in the `shell-mode-hook` or (preferably) add it the keymap for the mode like so

```el
(eval-after-load "shell"
  '(define-key shell-mode-map (kbd "C-i") 'foo))
```